# JBoss AS7 rewrite issue

Tags: url-rewriting, jboss7.x

I'm trying to redirect `http` connections to `https` in JBoss AS 7.1.1 using the `rewrite` valve inside a virtual host. This is my current configuration in `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
        <ssl name="my-ssl" key-alias="my-alias" password="pass" certificate-key-file="/path/to/keystore"/>
    </connector>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
        <rewrite pattern=".*" substitution="https://myserver.com:8443" flags="R,L">
            <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" flags="NC"/>
        </rewrite>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

The `http` port is 8080 and the `https` is 8443. Access to `http://myserver.com:8080` are redirected correctly to `https://myserver.com:8443`, but (this is the issue I'm trying to resolve) access to `http://myserver.com:8443` return an empty `HTTP 200 OK` response.

It is correct that JBoss apparently accepts `http` connections in the `https` port, or there is an error in the server configuration? If there isn't a error, how can I redirect `http://myserver.com:8443` to `https://myserver.com:8443`?

Comment: I know this question is stupidly old but did you manage to figure this out? I have the same issue and cannot seem to work around it without modifying the application's web.xml, and unfortunately that isn't something that is supported by the vendor.